# How to Start a Process through WCF WebService?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-store-apps

I am Doing a Project in Windows Store application.

In my Application I need to Open a Skype.exe.

I m Using Skype4ComLib.dll., So I am using WCF.

My attempt to Start a Skype through WCF is :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone/skype.exe");
```

It Fails to Start the Process.

Give me some suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you just cannot do it in a Windows Store application. All Store applications are sandboxed, therefore you do not have access to other processes.

If you want to start Skype inside WCF Webservice, Keep in mind that when you host your WCF service in IIS, IIS requires and allows no user interaction. This literally means that there is no UI to host your process.

Comment: So, the Ultimate Point is i have to forget it right? :P, Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: If you explain the task in more details, I'll bring something to the table. For Instance, why WCF?

Comment: Actually, In my project, I want to make a video call through code. Eventhough skype4comLib supports it, we cannot add the reference in windows store app. I was thought of that i can achieve through wcf.

Comment: This is not going to be an easy task... as far as I aware, there is no Skype API/SDK on WP8. So you have to implement it by yourself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj553780(v=vs.105).aspx